# PHP function can't do the recheck for the IP checking every time i click the button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I use the following PHP code to check an IP and port status. It works!
Then I make a refresh button to reset the displayed status so that people don't need to press F5.
The embed status is showing "refreshed", but the IP checking doesn't seem to work.

Here is the PHP IP checking:

```
function check($host,$port)
{
if(isset($host) && isset($port)){
    $fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.5);
        if(!$fp){
            $outp = '"onlinestatus/offline.swf"';
            }
        elseif($fp){
            $outp = '"onlinestatus/online.swf"';
            }
    } else {
    $outp = 'null';
    }
    return ($outp);
}
?>
```

Here is the embed control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadembed() {    
  var game=document.getElementById("embed1");
  var clone=game.cloneNode(true);
  clone.setAttribute('src',<? echo check($host,$port); ?>);
  game.parentNode.replaceChild(clone,game)
}
</script>
```

Here is the refresh button:

```
<a href="javascript:"
onmousedown="document.images['Refresh'].src='image/button_reresh_click.png'"
onmouseup="document.images['Refresh'].src='image/button_reresh_down.png'"
onClick="reloadembed();"
onMouseOver="document.images['Refresh'].src='image/button_reresh_down.png'"
onMouseOut="document.images['Refresh'].src='image/button_reresh_up.png'">
<img name="Refresh" src="image/button_reresh_up.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Are you aware that PHP code `echo check($host,$port);` will run just once, on page load? Even if your code were correct, calling JS function `reloadembed()` *will not* run `check($host,$port)` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `check` function returns a string so you need to enclose this value in quotes:

```
clone.setAttribute('src','<? echo check($host,$port); ?>');
```

**Edit:**

It seems to be the case that you're expecting the `PHP` function `check` to be called every time you call the `JavaScript` function `reloadembed`. This isn't the case. `check` is run *once* -- when the page is executed -- and so your `JavaScript` will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadembed() {    
  var game=document.getElementById("embed1");
  var clone=game.cloneNode(true);
  clone.setAttribute('src','onlinestatus/online.swf');
  game.parentNode.replaceChild(clone,game)
}
</script>
```

The `src` will always be `onlinestatus/online.swf`. You can see if you view the source code. To get it to work as you want you'll need to use [`AJAX`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp).

Comment: I enclose that in my php code:
   $outp = '"onlinestatus/offline.swf"';
Maybe your way is much better. I will change that.
But it can't fix the problem. ._.

Comment: You'll still need to quote it in the `JavaScript`. If not you'll be trying to use a variable called `onlinestatus/offline.swf`.

Comment: $outp = '  "  onlinestatus/offline.swf  "  '  ;  I did that lol. Really not easy to see it and sorry about that. And now i change it to quote in the JavaScript. The embed work normal, but the refresh button still can't check the IP status again.

Comment: How to check the error? It seems havn't any error there. Every time i click the button, it will restart the same flash display whenever the server status changed.

Comment: Well, you've only given it two options: `onlinestatus/offline.swf` and `onlinestatus/online.swf`, so if you're online it will only show you `onlinestatus/online.swf` and if you're offline it will only show you `onlinestatus/offline.swf`.

Comment: Yeah you got it. When the server is online and I go in my web, it will show me the `onlinestatus/online.swf`. Then I close the server and I click the button, it restart the embed player (I don't know is it that call) but still same thing. The `onlinestatus/online.swf`.

Comment: The PHP function `check` is only run once -- when the page is executed -- and when it was run the first time it returned `onlinestatus/online.swf`. It doesn't run again when you run the `JavaScript` function `reloadembed()`.

Comment: OH I SEE! God, it really a bad news for me. Have any way to refresh the checking? I'm new. I thought PHP that function can run many times. And I put it out of the `<HTML>`. Is it the problem source? I don't know.

Comment: I have searched AJAX before and I tried that because some people say that can check the IP status. But is AJAX can't check the other server IP because of the security issues, isn't it?